# Nifi SplitXML and EvaluateXPath performance and memory usage?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, apache-nifi

I am getting about **800-1000 xml per second**. Each XML about **50-60 KB**. I think of using **SplitXML and EvaluateXPath for XML parsing**. But I don't know that how **memory usage and performance** will be. Does these processors load entire xml to memory?

Comment: possible to create script to split xml

Answer (score 4):

In the processors' documentation there's a section named `System Resource Considerations`. This section tells you such risks.
[SplitXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitXml/index.html) is loading the whole content of the FlowFile into memory, but [EvaluateXPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXPath/) doesn't seem to do so. Instead of `SplitXml`, you can use [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) which doesn't load all of the document to memory.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of downstream processing are you doing? You may find that you can replace `SplitXml` and `EvaluateXPath` with record-based processors such as `UpdateRecord` or `QueryRecord`, using an `XMLReader` and/or `XMLRecordSetWriter`. Then you can deal with all records in the XML file at the "same time" vs having to split them out and do identical things to each.

Comment: I want to split nested XML to one xml part. In the some process, I must exract attribute of node. For example, A node(it has id attribute) has B child nodes. I must get each B child node as one flowfile with id attribute of A node. (Each output flowfile must be have id attribute of parent node)

Comment: Can I still split the file by tags? Would you please help me out on how to do that?